# Junit testing an Akka singleton actor: preStart() hook not called

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, akka

I would like to test a singleton actor using java in Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK (Build id: 3.0.2-vfinal-20131028-1923-Typesafe) and Akka is 2.3.1.

```
public class WorkerTest {

static ActorSystem system;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    system = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem");
}

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {
    JavaTestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
    system = null;
}

@Test
public void testWorkers() throws Exception {
    new JavaTestKit(system) {{

        system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonManager.defaultProps(
                Props.create(ClassSingleton.class), "class",
                PoisonPill.getInstance(),"backend"), "classsingleton");

        ActorRef selection = system.actorOf(ClusterSingletonProxy.defaultProps("user/classsingleton/class", "backend"), "proxy");
        System.out.println(selection);
    }};
}
}
```

the ClassSingleton.java:

```
public class ClassSingleton extends UntypedActor {

LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(getContext().system(), this);

public ClassSingleton() {
    System.out.println("Constructor is done");
}

public static Props props() {
    return Props.create(ClassOperator.class);
}

@Override
public void preStart() throws Exception {
    ActorRef selection = getSelf();
    System.out.println("ClassSingleton ActorRef...  " + selection);
}   

@Override
public void onReceive(Object message) {
}

@Override
public void postStop() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("postStop ...  ");
}   


}
```

The ClassSingleton actor is doing nothing, the printout is:
Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/user/proxy#-893814405] only, which is printed from the ClusterSingletonProxy. No exception and Junit is done, green flag. In debugging ClassSingleton is not called (including contructor and preStart()). Sure it is me, but what is the mistake? Even more confusing that the same ClassSingleton ClusterSingletonManager code is working fine outside of javatestkit and junit.

I suspect that the cluster setup might be reponsible, so I tried to include and exclude the following code (no effect). However I would like to understand why we need it, if we need it (it is from an example code).
Many thanks for your help.

```
Address clusterAddress = Cluster.get(system).selfAddress();
Cluster.get(system).join(clusterAddress);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy pattern standard behavior is to locate the oldest node and deploy the 'real' actor there and the proxy actors are started on all nodes. I suspect that the cluster configuration did not complete and thus why your actor never got started.

The `join` method makes the node to become a member of the cluster. So if no one joins the cluster the actor with proxy cannot be created.

The question is are your configuration files that are read during junit test have all the information to create a cluster? Seed-nodes? Is the port set to the same as the seed node?

Comment: No success, I checked the config, port etc., I subscribed for cluster domain events, no events, no deadletters however without the JUnit is fine. I appreciate if somebody could give me a working junit example (with config).

Comment: Update: I can setup simple actors, send and process messages, others still fail.

Comment: https://github.com/almendar/akka-junit-sample <- try this one. Does it do what you need?

Look at the `testWorkers` the last line. I've put there a `sleep` if you comment it out it does not work.

Comment: you saved my life! @almendar, I have flu right now and this issue together were life-threatening :)) many thanks! so timing is everything...

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!